# ReferenceError with eventemitter

Tags: javascript, node.js

i try to use eventemitter, but i have reference error with processLineByLine . in this code i have text multi-line file , and each line i convert to uppercase.every convert to uppercase is my event. what i do wrong

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

let events = require('events');
let myEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
myEmitter.on ('upper', async function processLineByLine(){ 
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('text.txt');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: fileStream,
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {
      console.log(line.toUpperCase());
  }});
myEmitter.emit ('upper',processLineByLine() );
```

Comment: 1. You don't need to pass that function as an argument. 2. You can not access an inline function even if it has a name.

Answer (score 0):

[(Async) function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function) define functions, but don't assign them to variables. What you need is an [(async) function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const {EventEmitter} = require('events');

let myEmitter = new EventEmitter();

async function processLineByLine() { 
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('text.txt');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {
        console.log(line.toUpperCase());
    }
}

myEmitter.on('upper', processLineByLine);
myEmitter.emit('upper', processLineByLine());
```

Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to do. In this code, `processLineByLine` will be called twice, once without arguments and once with itself as an argument.